# IShellItemImageFactory - returns icons for most file types instead of thumbnails

Tags: file, com, preview, windows-explorer

As I understand it, IShellItemImageFactory.GetImage() should return a thumbnail (ie, a preview of the actual file contents) for common file types (images, MS office, PDF) and a file type icon for file types that don't have registered preview handler.

However, when I use it, the only file types that seem to actually generate thumbnail previews are images (jpg, png, etc).  Other types (xls, doc, pdf) just return the icon.

Is this the expected behavior?  Or am I misreading how it is supposed to work?  In explorer on this system, I am able to preview the contents for MS Office files, which I assume uses the same underlying mechanism.

Is there a better way to capture a preview/thumbnail for common file types?

Comment: In Windows File Explorer, do you see thumbnails for pdf, xls, doc? If you don't, you cannot expect IShellItemImageFactory.GetImage to return them.